# Query Collection with Limited Read Access

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an offer collection which looks like this

```
export default interface Offer {
    id: String;
    sellerId: String;
    buyerId: String;
    offerStarted: Date;
    offerEndedOn: Date;
    offerEndedType: OfferEnded;
    offerEndedReason: String;
    messages: Message[];
}
```

Every user can only read the documents where hes either seller or buyer.

Can I somehow create a js query that gets all offers where for example the sellerId is the users uid?
Or does this not work because of the limited access? If so is there an alternative how I can get this data to the user live in the firebase environment?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you need to pass user id, to your backend, backend will look up user id and determine user role, base on user role backend will retrieve data.

Comment: I suggest making an attempt at solving the problem, then show us what you've done so far that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I havent actually implemented it yet but ive tried it on another collection. I have a user collection where every user only has read access on his own profile and when i try to query it like this firestore.collection("users").where("uid", "==, uid).onSnapshot(etc 
but it gives me a permission error.